# HTML input accepting only the form like '000:00'

Tags: php, html, regex

This is my first post (blushing...)
I need to have an html   allowing a duration entry from '000:00' to '999:59'. It should also allow for entries like for example '1:01' without leading 0's (but no alpha chars allowed).
After pulling out most of my hair, I came up with this but to no avail. The Regex thing is in fact my biggest worry. Here goes :

```
    <input type="text" name="edDuration" id="edDuration" pattern="^(2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]?[0-9]:([1-5]{1}[0-9])$)" title="Format: hh:mm" style="position:relative;" value="000:00" maxlength="6" placeholder="000:00" onchange="myFunc">
```

Thanks in advance for any tip. Dan.

Comment: You've tagged the question 'php', but in fact there's no PHP in this question, nor will there be any in an answer; the question is entirely front-end. The regex you've come up with is a bit of a mess; I suggest starting over, and using a regex testing tool such as https://regex101.com/ to allow you to build it and see it working as you write it.

Comment: Can't you use `<input type="time">` and let the (modern) browser do the hard part for you? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time

Comment: Simba and Ward - Many thanks for pointing me to these resources. Awesome ! (answers were so quick... unbelievable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is often a good idea to still validate on the server as client data can never be fully trusted. You should validate on the client only to save extra processing on the server (this is unrelated to the question, but it does address some of the comments you have received). I have modified the regex to allow whole numbers with no partials (only minutes, no seconds).

```
<html>
    <form method="POST" target="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
        <label for="dur">Duration:</label>
        <input id="dur" type="text" name="dur" pattern="^\d{1,3}(?::(?:[0-5]?\d))?$"></input>
        <input type="submit" name="submit"></input>
    </form>
</html>
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['dur'])){
    if(preg_match('/^\d{1,3}(?::(?:[0-5]?\d))?$/', $_POST['dur'])){
        echo $_POST['dur'] . ' is an acceptable duration.<br>';
    }else{
        throw new Exception($_POST['dur'] . ' does not match valid pattern');
    }
}
?>
```

[Pattern reference (includes breakdown).](https://regex101.com/r/skXFPt/2)

Comment: Phillip. I have adopted your Regex because it allows for simple entries like '16' for example. However it's too bad the Regex cannot reject entries of alpha chars as they are typed. I will also implement the PHP validation you suggested. Also thanks for the Regex pattern ref.

Comment: @stressless you can validate as the client types: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions | Just check on keyup and/or update, you can disable the submit until a valid condition is met.

Answer (score -1):

A regex like `\d{1,3}:(\d|[0-5]\d)` would work.

```
1:01 => match
12:13 => match
100:02 => match
1000:02 => not match
999:59 => match
999:60 => not match
```

Explanation:

`\d{1,3}` matches 1 to 3 digits,

`:` matches literal colon and then

`(\d|[0-5]\d)` means either any digit(one) - `\d` or 2 digits - `[0-5]\d`, where first is 0-5 and the second one is any digit.

Comment: `^` and `$` are not necessary in HTML5 pattern, the pattern is anchored by default.

Comment: **This works like a charm !** Problem solved and thanks for the accompanying explanations.